# How to create a link that downloads a new file instead of opening the source file (rmarkdown)

Tags: r, r-markdown

My rmarkdown code produces a html document. This document lists out the process that needs to be followed by front line staff at month end. The process flow requires users to open xl files, update a few fields (such as report month etc) and then run macros.

I have used hyperlink to the original XL files as follows
`[click to opel xl file](path/and/file names)`

- The above link opens the original file and the user is able to
  overwrite the original file, I don’t want this to happen.
- I want the hyperlink to generate a new file that would be downloaded
  so that       nothing happens to the original file. How to do this?

Please could you kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research, this can't be done using conventional rmarkdown!